# In Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2, my vim is already configured which I don't want

Tags: vim

I use vim on my Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. When I write code in Golang, it automatically shows syntax errors when I run `:w` and shows the result on location list.
I don't want that behavior but I don't know why it's happening. I guess my vim is auto-loading some default configuration files, but I don't know where it is.
Below is my `$HOME/.vimrc` but after I commented out all of them, the location list is still automatically opened.
Any idea how I can know where the config is?

```
set nocompatible

syntax enable
filetype plugin on

set showmatch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set autowrite
set belloff=all
set grepprg=git\ grep\ -I\ --line-number
set smartindent

set path+=**
set wildmenu
set wildignore+=*git/*

let g:netrw_banner=0
let g:netrw_liststyle=3

au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif

au FileType go compiler go
au QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
au QuickFixCmdPost l*    lwindow

nnoremap <silent> [b :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <silent> ]b :bnext<CR>

nnoremap <silent> [q :cprevious<CR>
nnoremap <silent> ]q :cnext<CR>
```

`vim --version` shows this.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)
Included patches: 1-2269
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      +sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-iU6mZD/vim-8.1.2269=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lcanberra -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lm
```

Comment: Is there a directory `$HOME/.vim/` ? Is there `$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/go.vim` ?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed one of my plugin was doing its work and after I disable it, the loclist never shown up.